# python pandas data frame group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a data frame that has been grouped by some axes and looks like that:

```
subject     trialcode     latency

14233664    neighbour     1367.319149
            nonneighbour  1191.277778
            nonsn         1717.916667
            nonwords      1447.948718
 52602716   neighbour     1297.745098
            nonneighbour  1262.578947
            nonsn         1358.280000
            nonwords      1898.157895
500051240   neighbour     1249.102041
            nonneighbour  1287.052632
            nonsn         1444.346154
            nonwords      1960.162162
```

Now I need to re-group this by 'trialcode' and drop thhe 'subject' column. I tried to do this with

```
data_group_mean.drop('subject',1)
```

but got an error

```
ValueError: labels ['subject'] not contained in axis.
```

Any ideas how to re-group this data frame the way I mentioned ?
thanks

Comment: You want to regroup again? Just call `data_group_mean.reset_index()` and then `data_group_mean.groupby('trialcode').mean()`

Comment: @EdChum This is the correct answer. Why do you leave a comment instead of answering the question?

Comment: Because you need to confirm first before I post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is because 'subject' is now your index because you grouped on it, you can either call `reset_index()` to restore it, after which you can then call:

```
data_group_mean.groupby('trialcode').mean()
```

Or in your initial call to `groupby`, pass param `as_index=False`